# Domain of the function fractional part of $sinx$

Tags: calculus, functions

Find the domain of the definition of the function

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left\{\sin x\right\}+\left\{-\sin x\right\}}}$$ where $\left\{x\right\}$ denotes Fractional part of $x$

My Try: first i excluded all the values of $x$ for which $\sin x$ is an integer, since fractional part of integer is zero.Now since $\sin x$ takes only three integers $0,1,-1$, the set

$$A=\left\{\frac{k\pi}{2}, k\in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$$ is excluded from the domain.

also the range of fractional part of $x$ is $[0, 1)$, so is the range of fractional part of $\sin x$ and $-\sin x$. Thus the quantity inside the square root is always Non negative.

so the domain is  $$\mathbb{R}-A$$

any corrections in my analysis, please welcome.

Comment: $\mathbb R-A$ is not the correct notation here. What you want is $\mathbb R\setminus A$.

Comment: @BenLongo: Both notations are common.